# Hoe to Enable Specific Payment Method for Specific Store Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment-methods, magento2.4

How to we enable specific payment method for specific store Store ? like as I want to enable COD only for French store. what is path of system.xml for COD in Magento 2.4 ?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Cash on Delivery?

You can activate that in admin if you choose the storefront you want to use CoD.
choose - stores- configuration - payment method and you will find cash on delivery there. If I understand you correctly